# WCF unable to invoke using Jquery (using Postman)

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I'm trying to invoke a WCF web service using Jquery.

I tried using POSTMAN tool to test it first, but I'm getting the following error:

> ***415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=--------------------------786732504131267602580545' was not
>   the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.***

This is my WCF Web Service Code:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int GetAnswers(int queNumber, string answer, string studentID);
```

This is following code i used for Jquery:

```
 var form = new FormData();
form.append("queNumber", "1");
form.append("answer", "abcpostman");
form.append("studentID", "11111");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://bschoolapp.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "soapAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetAnswers",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "120e3284-131e-478b-a766-48e8b8688323"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

What would be the reason?

I updated the code to the following

```
    var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://bschoolapp.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "soapAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetAnswers",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "7bddc01d-963d-495b-ba4e-c6cb53729fe3"
  },
  "data": "{\"queNumber\":\"5\",\"answer\":\"sample answer\",\"studentID\":\"11111\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I am getting 400 Bad Request

Comment: Reason for error: Your WCF-service expects XML-format, but you send data in JSON-format.

Comment: I have updated to this code... But still getting error...

Comment: var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://bschoolapp.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "soapAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetAnswers",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "7bddc01d-963d-495b-ba4e-c6cb53729fe3"
  },
  "data": "{\"queNumber\":\"5\",\"answer\":\"sample answer\",\"studentID\":\"11111\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});